# How to use cin object in colab cpp?

Tags: c++, google-colaboratory, cin

I am trying to run a simple cpp program in google colab. The cout object in my program works but the cin object doesn't work. This is my cpp program.

```
%%writefile io.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n=0;
    cin >> n;
    out << "The number is "<<n;
 return 0;
 }
```

A screenshot of the colab:
[image]

Comment: what is the meaning of "doesn't work" ?

Comment: It is not prompting to give input.

Comment: when I click the run-cell, the program simply prints the initial value of the variable. ( as if there is no preceding cin statement). Please see the screenshot newly added to the question.

Comment: Well, colab just runs your program and prints the output, it's not an interactive console or anything. First of all, Colab is not meant for C++, you're basically running a shell script that executes your program. You may for example pass a file with input in a script, so the C++ program will read from the file instead of stdin (./a.out < file.in).

Comment: What I would recommend: make a new cell with %%writefile blahblah.in 15, then run ./a.out < blahblah.in, it will print out, or whatever else you put in blahblah.in. It's not as cool as interactive console, but at least it works.

Comment: The input file method worked. Thank you very much. But is there any way we can achieve the interactive mode? On the other hand, it seems the interactive mode for Python works.